# Where is the “SPARQL” button in OntoRefine tab of GraphDB 9.5 Free Edition?

Tags: sparql, graphdb, linked-data, ontorefine

I wanted to transform tabular data into linked data. I was trying to use SPARQL construct to achieve this in GraphDB 9.5 Free edition.  From the tutorials in GraphDb website it says **"You can press  the button SPARQL from the right top corner to access SPARQL end point"**. On the new version GraphDb 9.5 there is no SPARQL button after i loaded my tabular data. How do i access the SPARQL endpoint so that i can do my Construct queries?

[image: OntoRefine]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GraphDB 9.4 we introduced an entirely revamped approach to converting tabular data from Refine to RDF. It includes a visual RDF mapping definition editor that allows you to describe the mapping in a very precise way and then either consume the generated RDF directly (e.g. download it) or generate a SPARQL CONSTRUCT query that produces the same RDF and tune it further to meet your needs. As such, the user interface has changed and using SPARQL is now done in a different way. Perhaps you were reading an older tutorial?

For more details on the new interface, please refer to the documentation: https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/loading-data-using-ontorefine.html (in general) and more specifically https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/loading-data-using-ontorefine.html#rdfize-data-using-sparql (if you need to do with SPARQL).